# Vb.Net Excel filter

Tags: excel, vb.net, filter

Need a vb.net code to filter excel.

Example filter column 2 by criteria: Apple. All results for apple will now appear within the spreadsheet.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you need to filter a dataset in vb.net code? Or get an Excel spreadsheet to apply a filter via interop?

Comment: Record a macro while applying the filter - that will give you a good basis for your VB.NET code

Answer (score 1):

**you can convert following example in your code**

```
'for filter column no 4 for null rows then delete null rows as following
With drywtmonthly.Sheets("input").Range("a1:u1")

    .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=""
    Sheet1.Range("a2:u600").Delete

    .AutoFilter Field:=4


End With
```

i hope it useful